# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches') pnpm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, pnpm

I am using pnpm version 7.29.3 , node 18.15.0 and npm 9.5.0. When I run **pnpm install** I am getting "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')"

Error Log:

```
npm verb stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')
│ npm verb stack     at Link.matches (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1119:41)
│ npm verb stack     at Link.canDedupe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1073:15)
│ npm verb stack     at PlaceDep.pruneDedupable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:426:14)
│ npm verb stack     at new PlaceDep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:278:14)
│ npm verb stack     at new PlaceDep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/place-dep.js:314:26)
│ npm verb stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:943:31
│ npm verb stack     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
│ npm verb stack     at [buildDepStep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:943:8)
│ npm verb stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
│ npm verb stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:207:7)
│ npm verb cwd /Users/test/08mar/project
│ npm verb Darwin 20.6.0
│ npm verb node v18.15.0
│ npm verb npm  v9.5.0
│ **npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')**
│ npm verb exit 1
│ npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1680070933204
│ npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1680070933204
│ npm verb unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1680070949125
│ npm verb unfinished npm timer idealTree:node_modules/.pnpm/@discoveryjs+json-ext@0.5.7/node_modules/@discoveryjs/json-ext 1680070953308
│ npm verb code 1
│ npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:/Users/test/.npm/_logs/2023-03-29T06_22_13_155Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried

rm -rf node_modules

rm -rf package-lock.json

removed pnpm store

Comment: Have you tried with npm or yarn? Same issue too?

Comment: @axel NPM is working fine

Comment: is there some relevant info in here `/Users/test/.npm/_logs/2023-03-29T06_22_13_155Z-debug-0.log` ?

Comment: Not more pointer in debug file